# handleOnBackPressed not working on one fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using navigation componetns with drawer and app bar in my program.

From home fragment, it has a recyclerview, and when each item is clicked, the nav_host_fragment host another fragment with the selected itme, using the following line:

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.doTimedTaskFragment, args);
```

The problem, is, I need to ask user if they want to give up the progress they made in the new fragment (doTimedTaskFragment) if they hit the back button in app bar.

I digged Google Document and in the following link gives how I should do it.
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back#java

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // This callback will only be called when MyFragment is at least Started.
        OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true /* enabled by default */) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                // Handle the back button event
            }
        };
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);

        // The callback can be enabled or disabled here or in handleOnBackPressed()
    }
    ...
}
```

However, `handleOnBackPressed()` never gets called, and I'm suspecting the line of code I've used above to direct to the new fragment, and I can't find a way to resolve this issue.

EDIT/UPDATE:
My question was originally asking how to handle clicking Navigation component left(back) arrow click behavior, and in my case, I overrode`onOptionsItemSelected` inside the fragment and code came to be way much cleaner and better than overriding inside `MainActivity`.

Here's [screenshot of my mobile navigation.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILLqM.png)

Comment: Are you certain it never gets called? It does exactly nothing.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I meant handleOnBackPressed() never gets called when I click the back button on app bar.

Comment: I suppose you are using Navigation component in which should be handled accordingly based on what you have set from your navigation xml, otherwise you need to check your navigation to a specific destination https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate

Comment: @Ric17101 Thanks. I actually got that linke of mine from the document, and realized there is an option to send a bundle along with it, so that's how I got it.

Comment: Nice! No worries :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OnBackPressedCallback` is called for back button on the device not the `Toolbar` back button. For the toolbar back button you have to set it up with the navigation controller.

In your activity's `onCreate`:

```
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
val nc = findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(nc.graph).build()
setupActionBarWithNavController(
    this,
    nc,
    appBarConfiguration
)
```

and then:

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    //Handle the toolbar back button here.
    val navController = findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    navController.currentDestination?.let {
        if (it.id == R.id.someFragment) {
            //do something here
        } else {
            navController.popBackStack()
        }
    }
    return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

Comment: Should I assume the second code snippet goes in my fragment?

Comment: No it should be in the activity

Comment: Tonthoni Okay. It is working as expected, thanks! It would be much convinient if I could do this in the fragment, so I have more control though. I have to do this in my MainActivity in my case, so... THANKS anyway!

Comment: @mjay To have more control you can create your own view to look like a toolbar and add in your fragment layout. It will be just like any other view in your fragment's layout.

Comment: That'd be a good idea for much complicated app.

Comment: For those who might wonder Java code I did, `if (navController.getCurrentDestination().getId() == R.id.your_fragment)`